# Tratar CheckBox com erro ou mensagem de sucesso

Tags: typescript, react-native

Tratei diferente. Seguindo um tutorial, separei o checkbox com uma função e onde renderiza só está o status. Ficou assim:

````
        this.setState({
            checked: !this.state.checked
        })
        alert('agora está ' + !this.state.checked)
    } ```


<View style={styles.bottomContainer}>

                        <Text style={[styles.bottomContainerText, { color: themes[theme].auxiliaryText }]}>
                            <CheckBox
                                value={this.state.checked}
                                onValueChange={() => this.checkBoxTest()}

                            />
                            {'Li e concordo com os Termos de uso*'}

                        </Text>

                        <Text style={[styles.bottomContainerTextBold, { color: themes[theme].auxiliaryText }]}>
                            {'* Concordo que os dados pessoais fornecidos acima serão utilizados para envio de conteúdo informativo, analítico e publicitário e para contato por parceiros DVinvest, nos termos da Lei Geral de Proteção de Dados.'}
                        </Text>

                    </View>


Agora ele retorna um alert com o status. True = marcado e false = desmarcado. Preciso tratar ele para: quando for true eu tenho a mensagem OK e false eu mando um alert pra ele marcar.
````

Comment: Código não tem um exemplo minimo, não entendi a parte do erro ou mensagem de aviso (que ao meu ver é muito melhor, erro é sempre problemático) e o qual é a sua duvida?

Comment: Eu tenho uma caixa à ser marcada pelo usuário que como padrão, vem como true (já marcada). Preciso que quando ele desmarque essa caixa, que ele tenha uma mensagem de erro que essa caixa precisa necessariamente estar macada para ele seguir.

Comment: em poucos código seria: `{!this.state.checked && 'Mensagem de problema'}` isso mostra uma mensagem de aviso!